# Typescript module augmentation - get a reference to the instance

Tags: typescript

I understand how to do a module augmentation works. However, I don't know how to get the object reference in the new method's implementation.

For example, I want to augment the es2015 Map interface.

In my code I have

```
declare global{
    interface Map<K, V> {
        newMethod(g: K): V;
    }
}
```

It works fine. I can see the new method in my other code.

However, when I try to implement this new method, I don't know how to get a reference on the Map instance, so I can call other method (e.g. get or keys)

I tried

```
Map.prototype.newMethod = k => {
   ...
   let leys = this.keys();
   ...
}
```

But that doesn't work.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use arrow functions when adding methods to a prototype.
This code:

```
Map.prototype.newMethod = k => {
   let leys = this.keys();
}
```

Compiles to:

```
var _this = this;
Map.prototype.newMethod = function (k) {
    var leys = _this.keys();
};
```

And as you can see, `_this` isn't pointing to the right instance.
Even if you compile it to `es6` and it will keep the arrow function it will behave the same because that's just how arrow function works.

Instead it should be:

```
Map.prototype.newMethod = function(k) {
   ...
   let keys = this.keys();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, that was simple. I didn't know that there was a nuance between a normal function and an arrow function. Thanks for the lesson @Nitzan!

Answer (score 1):

Use normal functions instead.

```
Map.prototype.newMethod = function newMethod() {
  let leys = this.keys();
};
```

Arrow functions are not just 'the cool new function syntax', you should make a deliberate conscious decision that you want arrow function semantics over normal function semantics.

Primarily arrow functions do not have bindings for `this` or `arguments`, it'll be bound to the closest lexical scope instead.